# Mongodb default storage Engine for 3.2.8

Tags: mongodb, nosql

As per mongodb default storage engine for 3.2 is WiredTiger but when i am starting my server (3.2.8) the storage engine being picked is Mmapv1.

```
mongod --logpath /data/db/log.log --dbpath /data/db --fork

"storageEngine:{
        name : mmapv1,
        "supportsCommittedReads" : false,
        "persistent" : true
}
```

I have not inserted any previous data using mmapv1 as storageEngine.

Comment: Did you try creating a new database, or was this just the admin/local schema?

Comment: Nice to know! What was you question, again?

Comment: The question was HOW IS THIS POSSIBLE? No database was created i just ran db.serverStatus() and it gave mmapv1 under storageEngine.